# Fastest way to find complex roots

Tags: c++, optimization

Using `a + i b = sqrt(a*a + b*b) * exp(i arctan2(a,b))` I arrive at the following way to compute complex roots. However, I heard that trigonometric functions rather use up performance so I wonder if there is a better way in vanilla c++ (no external libaries).

Example: Let `u+iv = sqrt(a+i b)`

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    double a = -1.;
    double b = 0;    

    double r = sqrt(sqrt(a*a+b*b));
    double phi = 0.5 * atan2(b, a);
    double u = r * cos(phi);
    double v = r * sin(phi);

    std::cout << u << std::endl;
    std::cout << v << "i" << std::endl;
}
```

This is just meant as a MWE, so it's not written in a class or method.

Comment: What's wrong about [std::sqrt(std::complex<>)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt)?

Comment: I didn't know that existed. I've actually written my own ComplexNumber Class and now wanted to implement this feature.

Comment: you didnt know about `std::sqrt` or about `std::complex` ? ;)

Comment: I didn't expect complex numbers to be available in the standard libarary, so I didn't know about neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is! I'm going to link a good explanation of the process here, but it looks like this can be accomplished by only calculating the magnitude of the original number and subtracting out the real portion of the original number and finally taking the square root of that to find the imaginary part of the square root. The real part can be found by dividing the imaginary part of the original number by 2 * the imaginary part of the root to get your final answer.
https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/Finding%20the%20square%20root%20of%20a%20complex%20number.htm
Let me know if you need more help with the code but this requires no trig functions.

Comment: Ah yes, this is actually straightforward. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this link is now broken.

Comment: Could you please provide an example and update the broken link?